# Selective timeout based events handling: immediate first, debounce next

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debouncing

Let's say there are random sequences of external actions (e.g. scroll events). I need to handle the first action immediately, then dismiss all actions occurred with intervals less than some given delta, and then handle the next one which should be delayed for that delta. Further actions should be processed in the same manner.

This looks like a combination of debounce-immediate and simple debounce. I prepared a diagram to demonstrate the idea.

[image]

What is the best solution/approach here? I wonder if there is some ready-made pattern...

**UPDATE**

I would like to thank all participants! For the research I created plunker with <del>four</del> five different realizations suggested in answers: https://plnkr.co/N9nAwQ.

```
const handler = [
  processEvent, // normal
  debounceNext(processEvent, DELAY), // dhilt
  makeRateLimitedEventHandler(DELAY, processEvent), // user650881
  debounceWithDelay(processEvent, DELAY, 0), // willem-dhaeseleer
  _.debounce(processEvent, DELAY, {leading: true}) // lodash debounce + leading,
  debounceish(DELAY, processEvent) //Mikk3lRo
];
```

A great news was the Lodash has a leading-flag debounce implementation which satisfies the issue (thanks to Willem D'Haeseleer). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718342/3211932) is the cool demo from Mikk3lRo' answer, he also provided some useful synthesis.

I investigated the sources and the results: form just [visual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDRjewpNnaU) point to memory  allocation stuff... I didn't find any performance issues, and the views seem okey. So the ultima ratio was the code itself. All sources were converted to ES6 (as you can see in [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/N9nAwQ/)) for I can compare them fully. I excluded my [own try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699605/3211932) (it is a bit excessive, despite I like how it looks). The timestamp version is very interesting! The postDelay version's nice, though it wasn't a requested feature (so that [snippet demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718342/3211932) has double delay for two lodash demos).

I decided not to have a lodash dependency (in other way I certainly would use [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) with leading option), so I chose `debounceish` by Mikk3lRo.

**PS** I would like to share that little bounty (unfortunately there is no such an option) or even take some more scores from my reputation for it (but not 200, is too much and would be unfair to the winner which would have only 100). I even can't vote twice... Nevermind.

Comment: Are you using something like RxJS?  Or do you want to write the algorithm yourself?

Comment: Vanilla JS would be preferable for me, but RxJS try is also ok, I think, because this task arose in Angular 2+ context initially.

Comment: How is this different from using lodash's debounce method with the leading flag ?

Comment: @dhilt I've added a comparison to my answer with a different visualization, take a look.

Comment: @dhilt don't forgot to accept an answer so the bounty will not get lost ! :D

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer It's a bit cruel that I must do it, but I will... thanks for all!

Comment: `share that little bounty or even take some more scores from my reputation` don't sweat it - once the bounty is granted, you can start another as long as doubling doesn't exceed 500.

Comment: @greybeard o, I see... But I can't make it of 50 scores or even 100. Only 200. (I think it's because of previous was 100.) So it's too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution in vanilla JS using a single timer:

```js
function debounceish(delta, fn) {
    var timer = null;
    return function(e) {
        if (timer === null) {
            //Do now
            fn(e);
            //Set timer that does nothing (but is not null until it's done!)
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                timer = null;
            }, delta);
        } else {
            //Clear existing timer
            clearTimeout(timer);
            //Set a new one that actually does something
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                fn(e);
                //Set timer that does nothing again
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    timer = null;
                }, delta);
            }, delta);
        }
    };
}

function markEvt(e) {
    var elm = document.createElement('div');
    elm.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;background:tomato;border-radius:3px;width:6px;height:6px;margin:-3px;';
    elm.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    elm.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
}

document.addEventListener('click', debounceish(2000, markEvt));
```

```html
<p>Click somewhere (2000ms delta) !</p>
```

Comparing 6 proposals using the same type of visualization:

```js
var methods = {
    default: function(delay, fn) {
        return fn;
    },
    dhilt_debounceNext: (delay, cb) => { 
      let timer = null;
      let next = null;

      const runTimer = (delay, event) => {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          timer = null;
          if(next) {
            next(event);
            next = null;
            runTimer(delay);
          }
        }, delay);
      };  

      return (event) => {
        if(!timer) {
          cb(event);
        }
        else {
          next = cb;
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        runTimer(delay, event);
      }
    },
    
    Mikk3lRo_debounceish(delta, fn) {
        var timer = null;
        return function(e) {
            if (timer === null) {
                //Do now
                fn(e);
                //Set timer that does nothing (but is not null until it's done!)
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    timer = null;
                }, delta);
            } else {
                //Clear existing timer
                clearTimeout(timer);
                //Set a new one that actually does something
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    fn(e);
                    //Set timer that does nothing again
                    timer = setTimeout(function(){
                        timer = null;
                    }, delta);
                }, delta);
            }
        };
    },
    
    user650881_makeRateLimitedEventHandler: function(delta_ms, processEvent) {
        var timeoutId = 0;  // valid timeoutId's are positive.
        var lastEventTimestamp = 0;

        var handler = function (evt) {
            // Any untriggered handler will be discarded.
            if (timeoutId) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                timeoutId = 0;
            }
            var curTime = Date.now();
            if (curTime < lastEventTimestamp + delta_ms) {
                // within delta of last event, postpone handling
                timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                    processEvent(evt);
                }, delta_ms);
            } else {
                // long enough since last event, handle now
                processEvent(evt);
            }

            // Set lastEventTimestamp to time of last event after delta test.
            lastEventTimestamp = Date.now();
        };
        return handler;
    },
    
    Willem_DHaeseleer_debounceWithDelay: (delay, func) => {
        let postDebounceWait;
        let timeOutLeading = false;
        const debounced = _.debounce((...args) => {
            // wrap the handler so we can add an additional timeout to the debounce invocation
            if (timeOutLeading) {
                /*
                 for the first invocation we do not want an additional timeout.
                 We can know this is the leading invocation because,
                 we set timeOutLeading immediately to false after invoking the debounced function.
                 This only works because the debounced leading functionality is synchronous it self.
                 ( aka it does not use a trampoline )
                 */
                func(...args);
            } else {
                postDebounceWait = setTimeout(() => {
                    func(...args)
                }, delay);
            }
        }, delay, {leading: true});
        return (...args) => {
            // wrap the debounced method it self so we can cancel the post delay timer that was invoked by debounced on each invocation.
            timeOutLeading = true;
            clearTimeout(postDebounceWait);
            debounced(...args);
            timeOutLeading = false;
        }
    },
    
    Willem_DHaeseleer_lodashWithLeading: (delta, cb) => {
        return _.debounce(cb, delta * 2, {leading: true});
    },
    
    Javier_Rey_selfCancelerEventListener: function (delta, fn) {
        return function(ev) {
            var time = new Date().getTime();
            if (ev.target.time && time - ev.target.time < delta) {return;}
            ev.target.time = time;
            fn(ev);
        };
    },
};

var method_count = 0;
var colors = ['grey', 'tomato', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'];
function markEvt(method) {
    var style = 'position:absolute;border-radius:3px;width:6px;height:6px;margin:-3px;';
    style += 'background:' + colors[method_count] + ';';
    if (method_count > 0) {
      style += 'transform:rotate(' + Math.floor(360 * method_count / (Object.keys(methods).length - 1)) + 'deg) translateY(-8px);';
    }
    var elm = document.createElement('div');
    elm.innerHTML = '<span style="width:.8em;height:.8em;border-radius:.4em;display:inline-block;background:' + colors[method_count] + '"></span> ' + method;
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
    
    method_count++;
    return function(e) {
        elm = document.createElement('div');
        elm.style.cssText = style;
        elm.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        elm.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        document.body.appendChild(elm);
    };
}

for (var method in methods) {
    document.addEventListener('click', methods[method](2000, markEvt(method)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I needed to make minor adjustments to some of the methods to get a common interface. Adapting Cully's answer took more effort than I was willing to put in considering the comments suggest it doesn't do what the OP wants anyway.

It should be pretty clear that Javier Rey's approach behaves completely differently from the rest. Dhilt, user650881 and my own methods seem consistent. Both of Willem D'Haeseleer's methods have double the delay (and other subtle differences), but seem to behave consistently too. As far as I understand the double delay is completely intentional, though that is not how I understand the OP.

> I would say that Willem D'Haeseleer's lodash method is without a doubt the simplest - if you already use lodash that is. Without external dependencies my method is IMO simplest - but I may be biased on that one ;)

Comment: Nice visualization of the various proposals together.  You might add a brief summary of the observations.

Comment: @user650881 something like that?

Comment: yes, regarding the summary of behavior. I would have left out the editorial on simplest.  Note there are more differences: 
William D'Haeseleer's debounceWithDelay and lodashWithLeading behave a bit differently if clicked between delta and two delta, debounceWithDelay appears immediately.  If you stagger 3 events just so you will notice my implementation prevents processing within delta from the last *event* while yours prevents processing within delta from the last *event handler*.  I implemented it as I read the spec, though it is possible yours may be what was actually desired.

Answer (score 1):

You might track the last event time and only create a timer event when a follow-up check is required.

```
function makeRateLimitedEventHandler(delta_ms, processEvent) {
    var timeoutId = 0;  // valid timeoutId's are positive.
    var lastEventTimestamp = 0;

    var handler = function (evt) {
        // Any untriggered handler will be discarded.
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = 0;
        }
        var curTime = Date.now();
        if (curTime < lastEventTimestamp + delta_ms) {
            // within delta of last event, postpone handling
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                processEvent(evt);
            }, delta_ms);
        } else {
            // long enough since last event, handle now
            processEvent(evt);
        }

        // Set lastEventTimestamp to time of last event after delta test.
        lastEventTimestamp = Date.now();
    };
    return handler;
}

var DELTA_MS = 5000;
var processEvent = function (evt) { console.log('handling event'); };
el.addEventHandler('some-event', makeRateLimitedEventHandler(DELTA_MS, processEvent));
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior in your visual is no different then the standard lodash debouncing behavior with the leading option, the only difference is that your only displaying half of the delta instead of the full delta.
Therefore, your solution can be as simple as this.

```
_.debounce(cb, delta * 2, {leading: true});
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

If you want the last delay to be longer, you can solve that by wrapping both the debounced method and the handler. That way you can set the timeout in the handler, and cancel it in the debounce wrapper.
You do have to check if the current invocation was the leading one in order to not add the timeout in that case.

It could look like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const bb = require('bluebird');

function handler(arg) {
    console.log(arg, new Date().getSeconds());
}

const debounceWithDelay = (func, delay, postDelay) => {
    let postDebounceWait;
    let timeOutLeading = false;
    const debounced = _.debounce((...args) => {
        // wrap the handler so we can add an additional timeout to the debounce invocation
        if (timeOutLeading) {
            /*
             for the first invocation we do not want an additional timeout.
             We can know this is the leading invocation because,
             we set timeOutLeading immediately to false after invoking the debounced function.
             This only works because the debounced leading functionality is synchronous it self.
             ( aka it does not use a trampoline )
             */
            func(...args);
        } else {
            postDebounceWait = setTimeout(() => {
                func(...args)
            }, postDelay);
        }
    }, delay, {leading: true});
    return (...args) => {
        // wrap the debounced method it self so we can cancel the post delay timer that was invoked by debounced on each invocation.
        timeOutLeading = true;
        clearTimeout(postDebounceWait);
        debounced(...args);
        timeOutLeading = false;
    }
};

const debounceDelay = debounceWithDelay(handler, 50, 2000);

(async function () {
    console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
    debounceDelay(1);
    debounceDelay(2);
    debounceDelay(3);
    debounceDelay(4);
    await bb.delay(3000);
    debounceDelay(5);
    await bb.delay(3000);
    debounceDelay(6);
    debounceDelay(7);
    debounceDelay(8);
})();
```

Runnable script:

[image: Edit 40zq8y59p9]

Comment: I've added a comparison to my answer. I needed to add the spread operator in the call to `debounced` to get the event arguments... Typo in your code or me doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that I think works the way you described.  If not, it's at least something to go off of.

```js
// set up the event bus

const start = getMilli()
const bus = createBus()
bus.on('event', e => console.log(`[${getPassage(start)}] [${e}] original bus: saw event`))

const wrappedBus = wrapBus(1600, 'event', bus)
wrappedBus.on('event', e => console.log(`[${getPassage(start)}] [${e}] wrapped bus: saw event`))
wrappedBus.on('skipped', e => console.log(`[${getPassage(start)}] [${e}] skipped by wrapped bus`))
wrappedBus.on('last before interval', e => console.log(`[${getPassage(start)}] [${e}] this was the last event before the end of the interval`))
wrappedBus.on('interval tick', _ => console.log(`[${getPassage(start)}] interval tick`))

// trigger events on the bus every so often

let totalTime = 0
const intervalTime = 300
setInterval(() => {
  totalTime += intervalTime
  bus.trigger('event', totalTime)
}, intervalTime)

function getMilli() {
  return (new Date()).getTime()
}

function getPassage(from) {
  return getMilli() - from
}

// creates a simple event bus
function createBus() {
  const cbs = {}
  
  return {
    on: (label, cb) => {
      if(cbs.hasOwnProperty(label)) cbs[label].push(cb)
      else cbs[label] = [cb]
    },
    
    trigger: (label, e) => {
      if(cbs.hasOwnProperty(label)) cbs[label].forEach(f => f(e))
    },
  }
}

// creates a new bus that should trigger the way you described
function wrapBus(waitInterval, eventLabel, bus) {
  const newBus = createBus()
  
  let deliveredFirst = false
  let gotIgnoredEvent = false
  let lastIgnoredEvent = undefined

  setInterval(() => {
    // just here so we know when this interval timer is ticking
    newBus.trigger('interval tick', null)

    // push the last event before the end of this interval
    if(gotIgnoredEvent) {
      gotIgnoredEvent = false
      deliveredFirst = false
      newBus.trigger(eventLabel, lastIgnoredEvent)
      newBus.trigger('last before interval', lastIgnoredEvent)
    }
  }, waitInterval)
  
  bus.on(eventLabel, function(e) {
    if(!deliveredFirst) {
      newBus.trigger(eventLabel, e)
      deliveredFirst = true
      gotIgnoredEvent = false
    }
    else {
      gotIgnoredEvent = true
      lastIgnoredEvent = e
      // this is here just to see when the wrapped bus skipped events
      newBus.trigger('skipped', e)
    }
  })
  
  return newBus
}
```

Comment: @dhilt Looking more closely at this, I think it will give you the next event AFTER the defined interval, not the last event before the interval. It sounds like you're wanting the last event before the interval time, is that correct?

Comment: OK, I changed it quite a bit.  I think this version does what you're looking for.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your code, I was happy to explore it! As I can see, you created some kind of throttling, not debouncing. If I set _wrapBus waitInterval_ < _trigger intervalTime_, I would see all actions handled without skip due to the interval will be always >  in terms of initial post (it's not the only use case breaking the requirements). I updated the question, added some details and I hope it became more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised it doesn't work exactly as needed.  Hopefully it's at least a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

```
const debounceNext = (cb, delay) => { 
  let timer = null;
  let next = null;

  const runTimer = (delay, event) => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      if(next) {
        next(event);
        next = null;
        runTimer(delay);
      }
    }, delay);
  };  

  return (event) => {
    if(!timer) {
      cb(event);
    }
    else {
      next = cb;
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    runTimer(delay, event);
  }
};

const processEvent = (event) => console.log(event);
const debouncedHandler = debounceNext(processEvent, 125);
myElement.addEventListener('scroll', debouncedHandler);
```